# What is the difference between using Solr's EdgeNGramFilterFactory at index time vs query time?

Tags: apache, solr, tokenize

I haven't noticed many differences, but is it that when you use EdgeNGramFilterFactory at index time the document terms themselves get broken into the substrings and then your search string is matched on these substrings, and likewise at index time the query you enter gets broken down into substring and is then matched on the normal document strings?

Is this a proper way of viewing this process or do I have a misconception?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per Solr Wiki :-

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory

Edge n-gram analysis can be performed at either index or query time (or both), but typically it is more useful, as shown in this example, to generate the n-grams at index time with all of the n-grams indexed at the same position. At query time the query term can be matched directly without any n-gram analysis.

So basically the generated n-grams would be close to each other if you you perform n-gram analysis at index time leading to better performance.

I view this as Arrays and Linkedlist. In Arrays the elements are closer to each other leading to faster traversal.